# GtkButton just shows text but no image

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I have a GtkButton inside a GtkHButtonBox that doesn't show the image I'm adding to it. It just shows the text. Here's the code:

```
GtkImage *image = (GtkImage *) gtk_image_new_from_file("Gateway-LT21-netbook-2-540x359");
GtkButton *button = (GtkButton *) gtk_button_new_with_label("test");
gtk_button_set_image(button, (GtkWidget *) image);
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the "gtk-button-images" setting is set to true.

```
GtkSettings *default_settings = gtk_settings_get_default();
g_object_set(default_settings, "gtk-button-images", TRUE, NULL);
```

Note: This should follow the construction of the first window (and of course precede the main loop).

If I'm not mistaken, this is a rather recent change in Gnome - for some reason, they decided for icons not to appear on buttons as default (this also seems to apply to the standard MS Windows theme).

Comment: Is this setting going to work for all the windows and dialogs?

Comment: What if I just want to show the image of one button and not all?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(image))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, at least in GTK+ 3 there is a function called [gtk_button_set_always_show_image()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-set-always-show-image), which is supposed to enable an image for a particular button regardless of global settings.